# Static file handler with MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC5, maybe 1 month now developing in it.

I've done some load testing on a script I just finished in MVC5/C# and am not as impressed as I thought.

I am trying to figure out if there is some sort of static file handling allowed with MVC -- Serve the MVC content as static?  I thought `output cache` (`[OutputCache(Duration = 1200, VaryByParam = "none", VaryByHeader="none")]`) would help with this, and even though it does, not much.

It loads quickly on a staging server with no other activity, but it doesn't do to well when there's a heavier load on it.

It's a standard MVC Controller > ViewModel in C# application that makes 4 db connections, takes around 700ms to load when no other users, and is around 150kb large.

Here are my load test results for 50 sim. users on this script (IIS 7.5):

```
 Normal:                   50.00s
 w/ Output Cache Enabled:  25.00s
 in HTML/Static form:      600ms
```

You can see the chart below:

[image]

Comment: Side note: Cool looking pictures without readable description is somewhat useless..

Comment: What other description is needed? The post + charts are pretty descriptive no?

Comment: If you actually have output caching setup correctly you should see almost the same picture as your static HTML. I suspect you somehow vary requests so only every other one hits cached item... Make sure your requests are actually should be hitting cache (i.e. all to the same Url).

Comment: I'm using `[OutputCache(Duration = 1200, VaryByParam = "none", VaryByHeader="none")]`  on the controller action. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Static files and dynamic content generation have there own use cases. I don't think you can compare the two scenarios. If you can do statically no point in even thinking about dynamic. Put the static file in server and give an anchor tag.

Comment: Output Cache works obviously getting better load times, just not as much as a static file.

Comment: 50.00 seconds for a page to load for a basic MVC page seems rather abnormal regardless of your other tests btw.

Comment: @Tommy with 50 concurrent users?

Comment: Yes.  I am not sure of your hardware, but here is a recent example (comparing web API vs MVC) - http://ajden.towfeek.se/post/Performance-measurement-ASPNET-MVC-vs-WebAPI.  He is seeing 2391 request per second (unsure about db calls).  I would be interested in seeing your test cases.

Comment: Is hardware really a question here? It's the same machine on all 3 tests.

Comment: No, but I bring it up to say, if you are running your tests on a intel pentium 3, it would explain a 50 second for 50 concurrent request test result.  But, if you are on a relatively new machine, your results seem rather high and I wonder if you have set up your tests correctly is all that I am proposing.

Comment: The fact is with output cache on it was twice as fast, as static file, it was 100x faster

Comment: Are you sure that you are running 50 concurrent requests (sessions) not 50 requests from one session? I'm asking just because asp.net session locks simultaneous requests for the same session (only one requests per time could be executed in not read only mode). Maybe it is not your issue but I would try to disable session and see what happens (decorate the controller with [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)] attribute).

Comment: Yes, I used loadimpact.com, besides, session state is disabled.  I was also trying to load the script during the load test and was experiencing long load times, so it's not that